# $G$ a group and $H$,$K$ subgroups, $kHk^{-1} \subseteq H \implies kHk^{-1} = H$?

Tags: group-theory

As post said, if $G$ a group and $H,K \leq G$ and for FIXED $k \in K$ does $kHk^{-1} \subseteq H$ imply that $kHk^{-1} = H$ ?

Comment: Engaging question, ***endorsed!*** By the way, I changed a "$K$" to a "$k$" in your title.  Cheers!

Comment: I didn't notice the typo, although I was distracted because \subseteq came up as $\subset$eq for some reason..

Comment: $K$ has no real role here, we can take arbitrary $k$ and set $K$ the cyclic $K:=\langle k\rangle$, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If $H = \mathbb{Z}$, it might be the case that $kHk^{-1} = 2 \mathbb{Z} \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}$. In fact this can actually occur in $G = \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, where we can take

$$H = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$
$$k = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right].$$

As Berci observes in the comments, $K$ plays no role in this question.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is finite, this is true, simply because of cardinality arguments. In the infinite case, this is false. You can try to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: You mean $H$ is finite, don't you?

Comment: Yes, yes. Merci, @Berci.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can reduce it (semidirect products) to the following: If $\phi$ is an automorphism of a group $G$ that takes a subgroup $H$ to itself: $\phi(H)\subset H$, does that imply $\phi(H) = H\,$?